# Prove that $\sigma_n - e$ is decreasing faster than $e-S_n$ given specific $\sigma_n$ and $S_n$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, summation

> Let $\sigma_n$ and $S_n$ be defined as:
>   $$
> \sigma_n = 3 - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!} \\
> S_n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k!}
> $$
>   Show that $\sigma_n - e$ is decreasing faster than $e-S_n$.

I may use anything before the definition of a derivative.
Based on the question we want to eventually show that:
$$
\sigma_n - e \le e - S_n
$$
Lets adjust $\sigma_n$. Define $a_n$:
$$
a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!}
$$
This may be expanded by partial fractions:
$$
\begin{align}
a_n &= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!} \\ 
&= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\cdot\frac{1}{(k+1)!} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{(k+1)!} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{k!} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{kk!} - \color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)k!}} - \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)^2k!}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{kk!} - \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+1)!}} - \color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)k!}} \\
\text{(telescoping)} &= 1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)!}
\end{align}
$$

Now going back to the inequality:
$$
\sigma_n - e \le e - S_n \iff \\ 
\sigma_n + S_n \le 2e \iff \\
3 - a_n + S_n \le 2e
$$

Replacing the terms with actual sums one may obtain:
$$
\begin{align*}
3 - a_n + S_n &= 3 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)!}\right) + 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k!} \tag{1.1} \\
&= 3 + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)!} + \sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k!} \tag{1.2} \\
&= 3 + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} + \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k!} + \sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k!} \tag{1.3} \\
&= 3 + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} - 1 + {1\over (n+1)!} + \sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k!} \tag{1.4} \\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} \tag{1.5} \\
&= 2\left(1 + \frac{1}{2(n+1)!}\left({1\over n+1} + 1\right) + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}\right) \tag{1.6} \\
&= 2\left(\frac{(n+2)}{2(n+1)(n+1)!} + \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}\right) \tag{1.7}
\end{align*}
$$

Which eventually results into:
$$
\frac{(n+2)}{2(n+1)(n+1)!} + \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} \le e
$$

Now based on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3082168/given-s-n-1-sum-k-1n-1-over-k-prove-that-e-s-n-le-fracn2nn):
$$
e - S_n \le \frac{n+2}{(n+1)(n+1)!}
$$

While I wanted to show:
$$
\frac{n+2}{\color{red}{2}(n+1)(n+1)!} + S_n \le e \iff \\
\frac{n+2}{\color{red}{2}(n+1)(n+1)!} \le e - S_n
$$

Or summarizing:
$$
\frac{n+2}{2(n+1)(n+1)!} \le e - S_n \le \frac{n+2}{(n+1)(n+1)!}
$$

Which [seems to be the case](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yw475vhizj). Now I got stuck. How do I proceed from here?

Description of the steps:

- $(1.1)$ - replace $\sigma_n$ and $S_n$ with sums
- $(1.2)$ - cancel $-1+1$
- $(1.3)$ - change indexing in the sum
- $(1.4)$ - add and subtract $1$ and change the index of the sum. Fetch last term of the sum.
- $(1.5)$ - add the sums.
- $(1.6)$ - factor out $2$. Factor out $1\over (n+1)!$
- $(1.7)$ - inject $1$ into the sum and change indexing. Cast brackets to a single fraction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming my cursory review of your work leading up to the inequality $\frac{(n+2)}{2(n+1)(n+1)!} + \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} \le e$ didn't miss an error and assuming $n \in \mathbb N$, we may proceed as follows:
\begin{aligned}\\
e-\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}
&= \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} {1\over k!}\\
&\geq \frac1{(n+1)!}+\frac1{(n+2)!}\\
&\geq \frac1{2(n+1)!}+\frac1{(2n+2)(n+1)!} && (n+2\leq2n+2) \\
&=\frac{n+1}{2(n+1)(n+1)!}+\frac1{2(n+1)(n+1)!} \\
&=\frac{n+2}{2(n+1)(n+1)!}
\end{aligned}

Seems to me that you did most of the work in your original question.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you!